# AWS StepFucntion Next State from a dynamic variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I am trying to go to a specific state directly or I want to have the flexibility to start from beginning of the workflow. I am not able to pass the next state as dynamic variable. How can I achieve this please?

workflow:

```
  {
    {
        "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
        "StartAt": "gotochoice",
        "States": {
            "gotochoice": {
                "Type": "Choice",
                "Choices": [
                    {
                        "Variable": "$$.Execution.Input.initial",
                        "BooleanEquals": true,
                        "Next": "$$.Execution.Input.startState"
                    }
                ],
                "Default": "defaultState"
            }
        },
       //Other states
    }
}
```

From above workflow I want to specify the start state dynamically. But "Next" is not accepting the variable from executionContext. Any workaround or any suggestions to fix this issue please?

Basically i just want to start my state machine from a certain failed state. I know below can be done, but i don’t want to create a new state machine for that.Any other alternative please.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resume-aws-step-functions-from-any-state/

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if anyone is still looking for an answer, this is not possible at this stage. But may be in future according to aws support.